# Exception thrown when trying to reach shared folder on network from Phone but not computer

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, shared-directory

I have a Universal Windows app that in the Computer version works as intended, it fetches files from a folder using:

```
IStorageFolder fileFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("\\\\192.168.10.106") as IStorageFolder;
Debug.WriteLine(fileFolder.Name);
```

which retrives me 192.168.10.106 and all i need.

Now when i try to do the exact same thing for the Phone version it throws an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Why is this happening?

The folder is setup to be read by all.
[image: Shared with all, ticked off that all can read]
[image: Security settings set so all can read]

Comment: Do you have the permissions on the folder set up to let users who don't have the same credentials to access the files? I'm guessing the desktop code is being run from the desktop where the files are stored (and therefore under a user with permissions to that folder)?

Comment: Thanks. I will look at this as fast as Windows 10 setup is done.

Comment: Updated with pictures. The folders are setup so all can read. Anything i am missing?

Comment: I don't read (I'm guessing Norwegian)? I'm assuming "Alle" means "All" (or everyone), which isn't the same as allowing anonymous users. All just means all users who are configured as users on the system. You need to add permission for anonymous users as well.

Comment: That is correct for both. I have tried to add the anonymous account but still no luck: [img]http://i.imgur.com/tEjarNR.png[/img]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. UNC paths are supported only in Windows Store apps (with appropriate capabilities), not in Windows Phone Store apps. See the table at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Comment: Actually there is an windows phone app in the store that can access unc-paths (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/sharefolder-explorer/9wzdncrdmmtk).  I really wonder how they did it.

Comment: They either have their own SMB code or are using a third party library to connect to the share. There is no in-box support to connect make the connection.